# Migration when the structure of the data class changes

Tags: java, android, kotlin, moshi

I hava a data class named `Subject`. In some situation, I need to serialize it and save it to a local file. Then, I need to deserialize it from the local file out of some reason. The problem is: when my app upgrade and the class `Subject` has changed, how can I keep the old data and deserialize it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself using
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialversionuid-in-java/

SerialVersionUID is used to ensure that during deserialization the same class (that was used during serialize process) is loaded.

This is to avoid problems. Otherwise you can use default values in new class members to read old values using new class.

Some custom serialization libraries have annotations for this:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization-jackson.html (including binary)

Comment: Thanks! I know `SerialVersionUID` and the `@Transient`, but it doesn't suit for my situation. If I use the same `SerialVersionUID`, it might crash after deserialized, the crash can hardly to be caught. So the solution can be:  map old data to the new class structure manually just like the DAO framework `Room`. But I don't how to implement it.